# Using a static_cast on non-pointer related types

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang, static-cast

I discover this compiler trick and I cannot find a name for. Have you any idea?
On an Intel processor, I can cast a variable from its base class to an inherited class. It works with MSVC, gcc and clang and I am very confused.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    virtual std::string print() const { return "A"; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    std::string print() const override { return "B"; }
    std::string printOther() const { return "other"; }
};

int main()
{
    A a;

    std::cout << a.print() << std::endl; // print A

    std::cout << static_cast<const B&>(a).print() << std::endl; // print A
    std::cout << static_cast<const B&>(a).B::print() << std::endl; // print B
    std::cout << static_cast<const B&>(a).printOther() << std::endl; // print other

    try
    {
        std::cout << dynamic_cast<const B&>(a).printOther() << std::endl; // throw std::bad_cast
    }
    catch (const std::bad_cast& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl; // print std::bad_cast
    }

    std::cout << ((const B&)a).print() << std::endl; // print A
    std::cout << ((const B&)a).B::print() << std::endl; // print B
    std::cout << ((const B&)a).printOther() << std::endl; // print other

    std::cout << reinterpret_cast<const B&>(a).print() << std::endl; // print A
    std::cout << reinterpret_cast<const B&>(a).B::print() << std::endl; // print B
    std::cout << reinterpret_cast<const B&>(a).printOther() << std::endl; // print other

    // error: invalid 'const_cast' from type 'A*' to type 'const B*'
    //std::cout << const_cast<const B&>(a).print() << std::endl; // print A
    //std::cout << const_cast<const B&>(a).printOther() << std::endl; // print other

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The most common result of UB is the appearance of working correctly.

Comment: Just because a C++ compiler compiles a program without errors does not have any guarantees that it's bug free or that it will work 100% correctly. As you continue learning C++ you will encounter this situation many, many times.

Comment: Add some data members to your classes and you will probably see that the phoney casts don't actually work, at all. And the name for this "trick" is, as others have indicated, "Undefined Behaviour".

Comment: Your confusion is caused by the expectation that incorrect programs will behave badly. Drop that expectation and you will understand, and also you will realise that this makes programming C++ a bit harder than you thought.

Comment: @AdrianMole I understand, the members of my inherited class are not allocated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `static_cast` can cast a class to a reference to a derived class. That is not a trick or compiler-specific. That is one of the specified purposes of `static_cast` in the C++ standard.

However, this cast has undefined behavior if the object isn't actually a base subobject of a derived class object.

In your case here you never created a `B` object, only a `A` object. Therefore all of the `static_cast` have undefined behavior and your program is broken.

---

`(const B&)a` effectively is defined to do the same as `static_cast<const B&>(a)` if the type `B` is a derived class type of the type of `a`. So all of them in your code also have undefined behavior and are broken.

---

`dynamic_cast<const B&>(a)` is allowed here since your class is polymorphic (has a virtual member function). It will work correctly and fail with an exception if `a` isn't actually a base subobject of a `B` object rather than causing undefined behavior.

`dynamic_cast` is the only cast that you may use if you are not sure that `a` actually is a base subobject of a `B`.

---

`reinterpret_cast<const B&>(a)` does something completely different than the above and also causes undefined behavior, because your classes are not standard layout and therefore definitively not pointer-interconvertible.

Comment: My first assertion is to think my program is broken. But on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/), every thing is well defined.

Comment: @Theo A program happening to give the output you expect doesn't mean that it doesn't have undefined behavior and isn't therefore broken.

Comment: @Theo Add some data members that are initialized in the constructors. You will see that the phoney `B` object isn't getting its data members initialized.

Comment: Thanks you, I understand what I can do or not!